# What is the slang English word for not structured programming code?

Tags: terminology, slang, programming

What is the slang English word for code that doesn't have structure: procedures, functions, classes etc. ?

Answer (score 9):

[Spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) ?

> Spaghetti code is a pejorative phrase for source code that has a complex and tangled control structure, especially one using many GOTO statements, exceptions, threads, or other "unstructured" branching constructs. It is named such because program flow is conceptually like a bowl of spaghetti, i.e. twisted and tangled.

Comment: Note that one of the major ingredients of spaghetti code is copypasta.

Comment: And if it's just a huge piece code invoking pretty same operations(not tangled I mean)? What we say in Belarusian slang language literally translates "cloth of code". Do we have an analogy for this in English?

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ , I'm thinking maybe 'redundant code'. See here: https://www.bing.com/search?q=code+redundancy&form=EDGNTT&qs=AS&cvid=d6a261ec34854754b2050f939200f5d4&cc=US&setlang=en-US

Comment: When we sit down for a review of such code, the speaker usually begins with, "This is mess."

Comment: While this is probably what he's looking for, spaghetti code usually refers to *over-structured* code, not *structure-less* code. I don't know of a slang term that really fits what he asked for.